# How can I configure JBoss 4.23 to accept long timeout connection?

Tags: file-upload, jboss, httpwebrequest

ALL, I am working on a project which need upload large file(200MB) from .net to JBoss.
so far I have set time out property to HttpWebRequest object, But still got exception in JBOSS Console Which is

```
10:31:06,896 ERROR [DeployServlet] Failed to upload file.
org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. null
     at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:359)
     at com.accela.deploy.servlet.RequestHandler.getUploadFileFromRequest(RequestHandler.java:86)
     at com.accela.deploy.servlet.DeployServlet.doPost(DeployServlet.java:118)
     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
     at com.accela.commom.filter.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:99)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)
     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
     at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:615)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:877)
     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:594)
     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1733)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.io.IOException
     at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalAprInputBuffer.fill(InternalAprInputBuffer.java:801)
     at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalAprInputBuffer$SocketInputBuffer.doRead(InternalAprInputBuffer.java:830)
     at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.doRead(IdentityInputFilter.java:116)
     at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalAprInputBuffer.doRead(InternalAprInputBuffer.java:738)
     at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:427)
     at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:304)
     at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.substract(ByteChunk.java:419)
     at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:327)
     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:193)
     at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.makeAvailable(MultipartStream.java:959)
     at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.read(MultipartStream.java:887)
     at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
     at org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:94)
     at org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:64)
     at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:354)
     ... 26 more
10:31:07,973 INFO  [RequestHandler] Failed
```

I believe this is because the http request time out issue. 
Is there any time-out config for JBoss accepting long time Http connection?  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you have run in to [this bug](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50394). If you are using Tomcat Native libraries, try deactivating them to see if it works then. Or use an Apache httpd server with mod_proxy and use the AJP connector on the JBoss server - if it really is a bug in the HTTP connector, that might be a workaround.

But to answer your question regarding the timeout, have a look a the file `server/default/deploy/jboss-web.deployer/server.xml` (replace `default` with the configuration you're using, if necessary). Make sure that in the element `<Connector port="8080" ...` the attribute `disableUploadTimeout` is set to `true`. See the [docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html) for more information on this attribute and the connector configuration.

Comment: I had created a new post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12725987/upload-large-file-to-jboss-issue), Please help to review it . thanks.